# FindOpenMP requires C or CXX language to be enabled error on Ubuntu 16.04. and cmake 3.5

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to generate Makefiles for "Hello World" like OpenMP program with cmake, but with no luck. If I compile it with `gcc main.c -fopenmp -o run` everything works great, so I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with OpemMP or gcc installation itself.

Here is my CMakeList.txt (for C program, but I tried for CPP too with the same results):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif()

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
project(HelloOMP C)

add_executable(run main.c)
```

When I run `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc ..` in my build dir I get this (without specifying compiler it's the same):

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:241 (message):
  FindOpenMP requires C or CXX language to be enabled
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/media/sf_Projects/OpenMP/Collatz/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I did lots of googling and couldn't find solution, so maybe here someone could help with it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the order of your statements is wrong.

Before doing serious stuff in your CMakeLists.txt file (and that's what `find_package` is doing internally) it is advised to initalize the project with `project` call. That checks for working compilers and adjust a bunch of internal variables.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

project(HelloOMP C)

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif()

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
add_executable(run main.c)
```

Comment: Oh my, it worked! Thank you very much, I was really frustrated :) You're the best!

Comment: I was also having a terrible time trying to statically link OpenMP to my project (on Ubuntu 20), and I found that using these explicit low-level flags ^ fixed it. The issue was that simply calling `target_link_library(target OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)` was being translated into `-lgomp` (which failed) and not `-fopenmp` (which worked) and that made all the difference. I no longer got undefined references to dlopen, dlclose, and dlsym after using this solution.